# How to invoke 32 bit powershell from 64 bit .net application without changing configuration platform from “Any CPU” to “x86”

Tags: .net, powershell

How to invoke 32 bit PowerShell from 64 bit .NET application without changing configuration platform from `Any CPU` to `x86`.

Comment: Run `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`.

Comment: `Runspace x32bitRunspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateOutOfProcessRunspace(null, new PowerShellProcessInstance(null, null, null, true));`